# Trouble Extracting Request Body in Flask-Lambda Application Deployed on AWS Lambda via AWS SAM

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, request

I'm encountering difficulties with extracting request data in a Flask-Lambda application deployed on AWS Lambda using AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model). Here's a breakdown of my concerns:

1. **Background:**

   - I've developed a Flask-Lambda application intended to handle various HTTP requests, including POST requests, deployed on AWS Lambda using AWS SAM.
   - Initially, I used SAM CLI to create a basic "hello_world" template, and I successfully built and deployed the application. GET requests function as expected.
2. **Issue:**

   - However, I'm facing challenges with extracting request data specifically in POST requests.
   - When attempting to retrieve the request body using methods like **`request.form.to_dict()`**, **`request.data`**, or **`request.get_json()`**, I consistently receive either empty dictionaries or encounter exceptions.
3. **Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

   - I've verified that the Lambda function is properly configured to handle POST requests.
   - The API Gateway integration request mapping templates appear to be set up correctly to pass the request body to the Lambda function.
   - I've ensured that Flask-Lambda is integrated correctly within my application and that routes are defined accurately.
   - Additionally, I've attempted to debug the issue by introducing logging statements in the Lambda function.
4. **Request for Assistance:**

   - Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to extract the request data successfully.
   - I'm seeking guidance on potential solutions or further debugging steps to resolve this issue and successfully retrieve request data in POST requests within my Flask-Lambda application deployed on AWS Lambda via AWS SAM.

Sample Input :

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"Bob",
    "age":"40"
}
```

Sample Code

```
import json
import boto3

from flask_lambda import FlaskLambda
from flask import request, jsonify

app = FlaskLambda(__name__)
ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = ddb.Table('mytable')

@app.route('/')
def healthCheck():
    data = {
        "message":"Healthy"
    }
    return (
        json.dumps(data),
        200,
        {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
    )

@app.route('/leads', methods=["GET","POST"])
def list_or_add_leads():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = table.scan()['Items']
        return (json.dumps(data), 200, {"Content-Type":"application/json"})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            # Extract raw request body
            print(event)
            print(request.body)
            # table.put_item(Item=request_body)
            data = {
                "message":"Successful"
            }
            return (json.dumps(data), 200, {"Content-Type":"application/json"})
        except Exception as e:
            data = {"exception":str(e)}
            return (json.dumps(data), 400, {"Content-Type":"application/json"})
```